# Table header at top of page while scrollable table contents not same width as table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table with a header that is fixed at the top of the page as the user scrolls the table headings still appear on the top of the page. But the width of the table headings is not the same as the width of the table. Here is an example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  thead
  {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  </style>

  </head>

  <body>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Heading 1</th>
          <th>Heading 2</th>
          <th>Heading 3</th>
          <th>Heading 4</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
            <td>c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4</td>
            </tr>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I make my headings the same width as the table?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbjwqsxm/)

Comment: When you use position: fixed, the elements are removed from the static flow of the page. They can't reference their original parent elements for size calculations. It's a bit liking moving them up to being a child of the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Please add tbody tag after completing this thead tag and remove position : fixed in thead class css